# Paracompactness properties of the line with multiple origins

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

Let $X$ be the "*line with multiple origins*", obtained by taking a set $S$ with the discrete topology and taking the quotient space of $\mathbb R\times S$ by the equivalence relation that identifies $(x,\alpha)$ with $(x,\beta)$ whenever $x\ne 0$.  This is a generalization of the classical [line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins).

Alternatively, one can take the Euclidean line $\mathbb R$ and replace the origin $0$ with many origins $0_\alpha$ ($\alpha\in S$).  Basic open nbhds of each origin $0_\alpha$​ are of the form $(U\setminus\{0\})\cup\{0_\alpha\}$ with $U$ a Euclidean open nbhd of $0$.

Of the following related topological properties (no Hausdorff assumption here):

- [paracompact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000030): every open cover has a locally finite open refinement.
- [metacompact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000031): every open cover has a point finite open refinement.
- [countably paracompact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000032): every countable open cover has a locally finite open refinement.
- [countably metacompact](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000033): every countable open cover has a point finite open refinement.

which ones does $X$ satisfy?

This should depend on the cardinality of $S$.

---

For $S$ finite, the space is paracompact (hence the other properties are also satisfied).

I don't know if this follows from general results, as $X$ is neither Hausdorff nor regular.  But here is an ad-hoc proof for the line with two origins $0_1$ and $0_2$.  The general case of $S$ finite is similar.

Suppose $\mathcal U$ is an open cover of $X$.  The subspace $Y=(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})\cup\{0_1\}$ is open in $X$ and homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, hence paracompact.  Intersecting every element of $\mathcal U$ with $Y$ gives an open cover of $Y$, and we can choose a locally finite open refinement $\mathcal V$ of that cover of $Y$.  Taking any element $U\in\mathcal U$ containing $0_2$ and adjoining it to $\mathcal V$ provides an open refinement $\mathcal V'$ of $\mathcal U$.

Now to show that refinement is locally finite.  For points of $Y$, that follows from the local finiteness of $\mathcal V$.  And for the origin $0_2$, suppose $V_1$ is a nbhd of $0_1$ in $Y$ that witnesses local finiteness of $\mathcal V$ at $0_1$.  The corresponding set obtained by replacing $0_1$ with $0_2$ in $V_1$ is a nbhd of $0_2$ that also meets only finitely many elements of $\mathcal V$, and the same of $\mathcal V'$.

---

What about when $S$ is infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is always countably metacompact (and thus metacompact if $S$ is countable since then $X$ is Lindelöf).  Indeed, suppose $(U_n)$ is a countable open cover of $X$.  Intersecting these sets with one of the copies of $\mathbb{R}$, we can get a point-finite refinement that covers that copy.  Now add on the sets $U_n\cap (S\cup(-1/n,0)\cup(0,1/n))$ for each $n$ to get a cover of all of $X$.  This cover will be point-finite except possibly at the points of $S$, if some element of $S$ is in infinitely many $U_n$'s.  To fix this, just remove each element of $S$ from all but one of the sets used in the cover.

On the other hand, if $S$ is infinite, then $X$ is not countably paracompact.  Indeed, if $S$ is countably infinite, then you can cover $X$ by the copies of $\mathbb{R}$ with each element of $S$, and this has no locally finite refinement since any refinement must contain a separate open set for each element of $S$ and these will all intersect any neighborhood of any of the origins.  If $S$ is uncountable, you can do the same thing by taking countably many of the copies of $\mathbb{R}$ and then throwing the rest of the elements of $S$ into one of them.

Finally, if $S$ is uncountable, then $X$ is not metacompact.  Again, consider the cover of $X$ by the copies of $\mathbb{R}$ for each element of $S$.  A refinement must contain a separate open set for each element of $S$ and then since $S$ is uncountable there is some $n$ such that uncountably many of them contain $(-1/n,0)\cup(0,1/n)$.

Comment: Couldn't you replace 'metacompact' with 'metaLindelöf' (or even 'submetaLindelöf') in the last paragraph?

Comment: Sure, you could.